# Find the equivalence class of this relation!

Tags: analysis, relations, equivalence-relations

I am having the following relation with the set A and B:

$$ (x_1, y_1) \sim_{A\times B} (x_2, y_2) \iff\; x_1  \sim_A  x_2\  \;\land\; \;  y_1 \sim_B \;  y_2 $$

I haved already proved, that it is a equivalence relation.
Now I search the equivalence class for $$\sim_{A\times B}$$

I know the definition of an equivalence class,
$$ [x]:=(y\in A\mid  x\sim y) $$

$$ ⟨x′,y′⟩∈[⟨x,y⟩]_{A×B}\ \textrm{ if and only if }\ x′∈[x]_A\ \textrm{and}\ y′∈[y]_B$$
Now I need a way to describe this:
$${⟨x,y⟩:x∈X\ \textrm{and}\ y∈Y}$$

---

**What is the amount of the equivalence classes of this relation? How can I write it down?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product/). Then you can write:
\begin{align*}
[x,y]_{A\times B} 
&= \{(x',y') \in A\times B\ |\ (x',y')\sim_{A\times B} (x,y)\}\\
&= \{(x',y') \in A\times B\ |\ x' \in [x]_A \quad \text{and}\quad y'\in [y]_B\}\\
&= \{(x',y') \in [x]_A\times [y]_B\}\\
&= [x]_A\times [y]_B
\end{align*}

Now, say we have $n_A$ different equivalence classes in $A$ and $n_B$ different equivalence classes in $B$. Then the number of different equivalence classes in $A\times B$ is $n_A\cdot n_B$.